# Is it possible to add an entire album to a playlist on Spotify?

Tags: android, spotify, spotify-playlist

Pretty much like the title says, is it possible to add an entire album to a playlist at once, instead of having to add every single track manually?
I can't find a way to do that, am I overlooking something? If it matters I'm mainly using the Android app.

Answer (score 1):

When you're viewing the album, tap the three dots in the top right corner and select **Add to Playlist**

- **[link1](https://community.spotify.com/t5/iOS-iPhone-iPad/Adding-a-whole-album-to-my-queue/m-p/4712311/highlight/true#M110838)**
- **[link2](https://community.spotify.com/t5/iOS-iPhone-iPad/Add-entire-album-to-playlist/m-p/4601608/highlight/true#M106439)**
- **[link3](https://community.spotify.com/t5/iOS-iPhone-iPad/Cannot-add-album-to-playlist/td-p/4779290)**

Comment: The option is not present, at least for me.

Comment: well, not sure how to advise you further. I found these which confirms it: [link1](https://community.spotify.com/t5/iOS-iPhone-iPad/Adding-a-whole-album-to-my-queue/m-p/4712311/highlight/true#M110838), [link2](https://community.spotify.com/t5/iOS-iPhone-iPad/Add-entire-album-to-playlist/m-p/4601608/highlight/true#M106439), [link3](https://community.spotify.com/t5/iOS-iPhone-iPad/Cannot-add-album-to-playlist/td-p/4779290). Maybe this option is avail only on Desktop version